# Add and remove items from the customer’s item-list using ember.js relationships

Tags: ember.js

I’m building my first app with ember.js and have this problem:

The *customer* should be able to add and remove *items* from the list. The standard way to do this is by creating a new *item* and add it to the *customer*.

```
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend(
{
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),
    items: DS.hasMany('item')
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend(
{
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My problem is that I can’t perform magic and let an item appear, I have to select one from my item pool, assign it to the customer and when removing the item form the customer I have to put it back into my item pool.

How do I remove the relationship between the objects without destroying any of the objects themselves? Meaning I’d like to let the foreign key jump around like I’m able to in a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve H. It wasn’t exactly what I meant, but thanks to your help I could figure it out myself.

I had to add a few lines to your *removeItem* function

```
removeItem: function (item)
{
    this.get('store').find('customer', 0).then(function (myPool)
    {
        this.get('items').removeObject(item);
        myPool.get('items').pushObject(item);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an item from a customer like this:

In CustomerEditController:

```
removeItem: function(item) {
    this.get('items').removeObject(item);
}
```

and then in your customer edit template:

```
{{#each items}}
    {{this.description}}<button {{action removeItem this}}>remove item</button>
{{/each}}
```